# how to fetch data using foreach

Tags: php

```
<input name="auth[]" type="text" id=" " value="<?php echo $cite_aut[$i]; ?>">
```

Above are text fields in html. Now how to get text fields values in a array variable in another php page. 
I tried it by using foreach loop (`foreach($val as $_POST['author']`)... but it fetch 1 extra value for $val, if there are 5 text boxes then it is fetching 6 values, 6th value is "array".

can someone explain how to do it?

Comment: if you want to get some data from an HTML page, please, post HTML code, not PHP

Comment: Shouldn't it be `foreach($_POST['author'] as $val)`?

Comment: Your `foreach` is backwards. The operands are `foreach (collection as item)` or `foreach (collection as index => item)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be:

```
foreach($_POST['auth'] as $key => $val) {
  ......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TRY

```
foreach($_POST['auth'] as $key => $val) {
  echo $val;
}
```